# Remove padding between table's images

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding, spacing

I cannot, for the life of me, get rid of the padding between the logo and the other images below it. I have circled the spacing. The images should be flush up against each other. No white space. What am I missing?

[image: screenshot]

My code:

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

tr {
  padding: 0px;
}

td {
  padding: 0px;
}

td.purpSpacerAlign {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="9">
      <img src="images/logo_lt.gif"></td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <img src="images/logo_rt.gif"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="images/purple_line_lt.gif" width="23" height="27"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="images/nav_grad_home.gif"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="32"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="32"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="32"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="32"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="32"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="5"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="20"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="images/logo_crafts.gif"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="images/top_grad_line.gif"></td>
    <td class="purpSpacerAlign">
      <img src="images/spacer_purple.gif"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any context, this is challenging to answer. I'm assuming this is an HTML table?  While this is only a work-around, (Without seeing your code),

try adding this to your html to see if it helps:

```
<style>
* { margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0}
</style>
```

Comment: I tried adding the internal style, but it did nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Directly on element

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

Using CSS

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 0;
}
```